# IE7 radio button issue when created dynamically

Tags: jquery, forms, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, radio-button

I have an issue in IE7 when I am creating clones of radio buttons. I am dynamically updating the name and ID attributes, however, I still have the issue that a radio button being checked resets any of the others which have been created dynamically. Any idea how this can fixed? [Here is a fiddle of the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/w9UJ8/)

This is the JS code which manipulates the form fields:

```
// Dropdown select
$('#quantity').live("change", function(){

    $('.questions_clonable:not(.questions_clonable:first)').remove();


    // Get value of selection
    var num = $(this).val();

    var cloned_el = $('.questions_clonable').clone();   

    if (num > 1)
    {  
        for (var i = 1; i < num; i++)
        {
            // Assign cloned block to new var
            var new_block = cloned_el;  

             // Store previous number for replacing with current in cloned block input fields
                var prev = i-1;

                // Update input name to make it unique
                new_block.find('input').each(function() {     
                    this.name = this.name.replace(prev, i); 
                    this.id = this.id + i; 
                });

            // Bit of a workaround needed to clone properly, reiterating class name
            $('.multiple_questions_container').append('<span class="questions_clonable hidden">'+new_block.html()+'</span>');

        }   
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found several possible fixes for this but the following worked perfectly:

```
function setElementName(elems, name) {
        if ($.browser.msie === true){
            $(elems).each(function() {
                this.mergeAttributes(document.createElement("<input name='" + name + "'/>"), false);
            });
        } else {
            $(elems).attr('name', name);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

IE7 has problems with dynamically created radio buttons, which is weird because it's such an amazing browser. It seems IE7 won't let you rename the `name` attribute of radio buttons.

[Here](http://code.rawlinson.us/2006/03/another-ie-gotcha-dynamiclly-created.html) is a possible workaround.