# why is document.getElementsByName("name") is not returning any values?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I am creating an html element and assigning id and name values programmatically and later when i am trying to access those elements by name it is not returning any value
say for example i create a html input element and assign id = "Number_1" and name = "Name_1"

```
document.getElementsByName("Name_1").length is always 0
```

where as below code works and returns correct value

```
document.getElementById("Number_1" ).name = "Name_1"
```

why is this happening?

```
var count = 0;
    for(var i =0;i<SomeValue;i++){
       count++;
       var cell = row.insertCell(i);
       cell.className = "lineItemTable";
       var inputElement = document.createElement("input");
       inputElement.type = "text";
       inputElement.id =  "Number_"+count;
       inputElement.name="Name_"+count;
       cell.appendChild(inputElement);
    }
```

Comment: Show us your html.

Comment: Are you running your code *after* the DOM is ready?

Comment: @kkk please check my update, which contains some interesting info you may have figured out by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Internet Explorer, you can't add a "name" after creating the element:

```
var inputElement = document.createElement("<input name='Name_" + count + "'>");
```

You have to create it like that, providing the name as an attribute in the "html".

---

*edit* — OK this is rich.

At some point, Microsoft published [this note](http://goo.gl/Od72HE) in their "Compat Cookbook". Key point:

> As of Windows Internet Explorer 9, the createElement triggers an "object not found" exception when you use angle brackets (< >).

That note contains a link to the [documentation for the `createElement` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536389%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which *still* insists that the "NAME"  attribute can only be set by using the "eTag" text, as in my example above.

Thus it looks like what you need to do is something like this:

```
function makeInput( name ) {
  try {
    return document.createElement("<input name='" + name + "'>");
  }
  catch (x) {
    var inp = document.createElement("input");
    inp.name = name;
    return inp;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is really an issue in IE?  Seriously?  Wow.

Comment: @RocketHazmat hard to believe but it's true. At least it's clearly documented on the MSDN site.

Comment: I thought that was only an issue with radio buttons, @Pointy . . . that's the only place that I've ever run into the issue.

Comment: @talemyn From the MSDN documentation: "Attributes can be included with the eTag as long as the entire string is valid HTML. To include the NAME attribute at run time on objects created with the createElement method, use the eTag.".  The "eTag" is the parameter passed in to the `createElement` function. The "NAME" attribute is the only one called out that way on the documentation page.

Comment: @talemyn actually check my update. MSDN has really gone downhill over the past few years.

Comment: @Pointy - Yeah, that is an "interesting" article . . . they say to include the `name` in the `eTag` and then show it being added afterwards for the buttons in their sample code.   LOL   I've run into this issue a couple of times in the last year and, in practice, I've only ever had to use a special approach for dynamically created radio buttons . . . all of the other inputs were fine with a `name` attribute added post-creation.

Comment: @Pointy - for more information on what I found, check out this SO thread, where I got started when trying to figure out why I couldn't select my options in IE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585939/ie7-radio-button-issue-when-created-dynamically (which lead me to this article, and the eventual solution that I ended up using: http://code.rawlinson.us/2006/03/another-ie-gotcha-dynamiclly-created.html).